# Using $parse for nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which is using a directive as well:

```
<parent-directive onsuccess="callback(param)">
   <nested-directive onsuccess="callback(param)">
   </nested-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

The nested directive is using `$parse()` to evaluate the function:

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs)
{
var fn = $parse(attrs.onsuccess);
fn(scope, {param: "myParam"});
}
```

My question: how can I set the function one directive higher (in the parent directive), so that the function can be set in the scope of the parent directive (which creates it's own scope)

Comment: Do you mean that you want `parent-directive` to invoke its `onsuccess` function in response to a `nested-directive` invoking its? Also, does `parent-directive` have an isolate or a child scope?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. And yes, parent-directive has an isolated scope, which I'm currently converting to a child scope (I was guessing an isolated scope isn't the way to go ;-)

Comment: An isolate scope *could* be the way to go - it depends on what you want. But with isolate scope, `nested-directive` will be outside of the `parent-directive` scope

Comment: yes, that was something I forgot. So to summarize: nested-directive is a child of parent-directive. How can I let the nested-directive invoke the onsuccess function defined in the parent directives attribute with callback(param). thanks.

Comment: Well, if the parent has `scope: true`, then the same function is also available to the `nested-directive` - there shouldn't be any issue. I feel like this example is a stripped version of what you are after, so the use case is not clear to me

Comment: I'm probably making this more difficult then necessary. My parent directive does need an isolated scope. So I've converted it back. The issue still exists, how can I invoke the function from within the nested directive setting the function in the parent. The nested directive can be used stand alone. If so, the callback is currently working correctly (using $parser)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76856/discussion-between-new-dev-and-roy-milder).

Answer (score 1):

New Dev helped me out.

it was just as simple as adding:

scope: {onsuccess:"&"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'require' config property in the "nestedDirective" config setting. This will give you the access to the controller of the "parentDirective".

```
{
require: '^parentDirective',
link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
   parentCtrl.exec($parse(attrs.onsuccess))
 }
}
```

Implement a 'exec' function in the controller of the parentDirective that will execute this passed function in its scope.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't an option. The nested directive has to work stand alone as well using $parse